# laravel blade include files with relative path

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In laravel blade system when we want to include a partial blade file we have to write the full path every time for each file. and when we rename a folder then we will have to check every @include of files inside it. sometimes it would be really easy to include with relative paths. is there any way to do that?

for example we have a blade file in this path :

```
resources/views/desktop/modules/home/home.blade.php
```

and I need to include a blade file that is near that file :

```
@include('desktop.modules.home.slide')
```

with relative path it would be something like this :

```
@include('.slide')
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Like: `@include('./././slide')`??

Comment: but a "relative" path would be with ../

Comment: I read a few minutes ago blade doesn't allow relative path. I think it always get from route, because I always need to put full path. A better choice is to create the detail components using VUE, despite to use @include.

Answer (score 8):

if someone still interest with relative path to current view file, put this code in the boot method of AppServiceProvider.php or any provider you wish

```
    Blade::directive('relativeInclude', function ($args) {
        $args = Blade::stripParentheses($args);

        $viewBasePath = Blade::getPath();
        foreach ($this->app['config']['view.paths'] as $path) {
            if (substr($viewBasePath,0,strlen($path)) === $path) {
                $viewBasePath = substr($viewBasePath,strlen($path));
                break;
            }
        }

        $viewBasePath = dirname(trim($viewBasePath,'\/'));
        $args = substr_replace($args, $viewBasePath.'.', 1, 0);
        return "<?php echo \$__env->make({$args}, \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?>";
    });
```

and then use

```
    @relativeInclude('partials.content', $data)
```

to include the content.blade.php from the sibling directory called partials

good luck for everyone

Comment: Good solution! Works for me on Laravel 8.

Answer (score 4):

There’s a (now unmaintained) package doing both relative and absolute includes ([`lfukumori/laravel-blade-include-relative`](https://packagist.org/packages/lfukumori/laravel-blade-include-relative)) working with `@include`, `@includeIf`, `@includeWhen`, `@each` and `@includeFirst` directives. I just pulled it in a project, it works well.

Answer (score 3):

A sleek option, in case you want to organise view files in sub-folders:

```
public function ...(Request $request) {
    $blade_path = "folder.subfolder.subsubfolder.";
    $data = (object)array(
        ".." => "..",
        ".." => $..,
        "blade_path" => $blade_path,
    );
    return view($data->blade_path . 'view_file_name', compact('data'));
}
```

Then in the view blade (or wherever else you want to include):

```
@include($blade_path . 'another_view_file_name')
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to create custom blade directive for that, the native `include` directive doesn't work like that.

read this page to learn how to create custom blade directive :

https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-about-writing-custom-blade-directives

```
\Blade::directive('include2', function ($path_relative) {
    $view_file_root = ''; // you need to find this path with help of php functions, try some of them.
    $full_path = $view_file_root . path_relative;
    return view::make($full_path)->render();
});
```

then in blade file you can use relative path to include view files :

```
@include2('.slide')
```

I tried to tell you the idea. try and test yourself.

Comment: Please include the essence of the solution in your answer, as it otherwise might become useless if the linked website changes or goes offline.